# Properly capitalising subsections with the cleveref package

Tags: cleveref

I have some trouble getting the references to subsections working precisely the way I want it with the `cleveref` package.

I want to reference subsections with the `cleveref` package in such a way that it capitalises whenever I reference to a specific subsection (i.e. using `\cref{}`) but not when just talking about some subsection (i.e. `\namecref{}`).

As `cleveref` usually only links up to the corresponding section, I introduce the `\crefname{}` and `\crefformat{}` commands. Unfortunately the capitalisation with `\cref{}` does not work and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
\crefformat{subsection}{#2Subsection~#1#3}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{First Subsection}\label{firstSubsection}

In this \namecref{firstSubsection} I would expect \cref{firstSubsection} to be capitalised.

\end{document}
```

I do understand that I could force this by using `\Cref{}` instead, but this is not the intended use of `\Cref` as by the package documentation, thus I must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, nice first question, thank you for including code and a clear description, I hope someone can answer soon!

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\crefformat{subsection}{#2Subsection~#1#3}}` works, but don't ask me why cleveref resets them at begin document.

Comment: You wrote, "I do understand that I could force this by using `\Cref{}` instead, but this is not the intended use of `\Cref` as by the package documentation". Are you sure about this? Where in the package documentation is your claim supported?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I believe that `cleveref` defers many actions until the `\AtBeginDocument` stage in part because many language-specific customizations are allowed and many `babel`-related actions are also deferred to that stage.

Comment: @Mico yes, but it is quite mysterious why here as babel is not loaded and why \crefname can be defined but \crefformat not (and why the documentation doesn't say something about this, at least I didn't find it).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you, I will use \AtBeginDocument{} for now.

Comment: @Mico, in the Typesetting Section of the package documentation it says "As it is very difficult for LATEX to determine whether a cross-reference appears at the beginning of a sentence or not, a beginning-of-sentence variant exists:
\Cref{}." I take from this that \Cref{} is only intended to be used at the beginning of sentences.

Comment: @AriRaven - Just because a command -- `\Cref` -- has been created to handle start-of-sentence formatting issues easily does *not* imply that the command must *only* be used at the start of a sentence. Here's *my* take: `\Cref` was indeed designed to capitalize a letter -- specifically, the first letter in a word -- in order to simplify the process of creating cross-references in certain situations. But this does *not* imply that there can be no other circumstances in which using `\Cref` would be useful. I'd say that your use case is a fine example of just such a circumstance.

Comment: @Mico I agree, but I think the OP has a point here. For example, section 7.1 on page 10 suggests using `\Cref` in other places might be unwise. This isn't stated, but the reasons given for not using `\cref` at the beginning of sentences seem to apply equally to not using `\Cref` elsewhere. Perhaps it's just that the package isn't designed for the OP's desiderata?

Comment: @cfr - Thanks! FWIW, I've been an active user of `cleveref`'s macros for my own papers ever since `cleveref` was first released some 15 years ago or so, and I've corresponded regularly with Toby Cubitt on a number of cleveref-related topics over the years. (I may even be the one "responsible" for Toby creating the global options capitalise, nameinlink, and noabbrev.) One thing I can confirm is that Toby tends to be very, ahem, careful about conceding additional use cases for his package's macros. :-) In contrast, I can see no real downsides to being a bit more open-minded in this regard...

Comment: @Mico Oddly, that doesn't seem to be in the manual ;). I didn't mean you were wrong. You know the package much better than I do. Just I could understand the OP's reservations given the way it's put in the documentation. I've been trying to switch to cleveref, but it's hard to take the leap for existing code, I guess.

Comment: @cfr - All I have to show for is an honorable mention in the thank-you section on p. 28 of the cleveref manual. :-)

Comment: @Mico I meant more your description of the author's approach, but I don't think you need to prove your bona fides!

Comment: @cfr - I know, I know. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't hesitate to use `\Cref` for the use case at hand. I think it's perfectly ok to add the instructions

```
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
\Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
```

in the preamble and to use `\Cref` in the body of the document whenever I want to generate the label "Subsection" (or "Subsections", in case there's more than one subsection-type item in the list of arguments of `\Cref`) rather than "subsection" (or "subsections").

Now, it is the case that differences in the behavior of `\cref` and `\Cref` are not *necessarily* limited to the use of a lowercase or uppercase letter for the first letter in the name label. For instance, if English is the language option in force and if the first two equations of a document need to be cross-referenced, `\cref{eq:1}` and `\cref{eq:1,eq:2}` generate "eq. (1)" and "eqs. (1) and (2)", respectively, whereas `\Cref{eq:1}` and `\Cref{eq:1,eq:2}` will generate "Equation (1)" and "Equations (1) and (2)". Put differently, `\Cref` not only changes "e" to "E" but can also be instructed not to abbreviate the name label.

Importantly, though, the only two item types that get abbreviated by `\cref` but not by `\Cref` when the English-language option is in effect are `equation` and `figure`. Since nobody would appear to be arguing that `subsection`-type items should be abbreviated by `\cref` (to "subsec." and "subsecs."??) in the first place, and since applying `\Cref` to `subsection`-type items in no way interferes with how `\cref` and `\Cref` operate on `equation` and `figure`-type items, there's no reason *not* to use `\Cref` in the way set forth at the start of this answer, is there?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % 'nameinlink' is optional
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
\Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}


\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{section}    \label{firstSection}
\refstepcounter{subsection} \label{firstSubsection}


\namecref{firstSection}, \nameCref{firstSection}

\namecref{firstSubsection}, \nameCref{firstSubsection}

\cref{firstSection}, \Cref{firstSection}

\cref{firstSubsection}, \Cref{firstSubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1, of course.) Well, there is one reason: it makes it harder to switch later because it's non-semantic markup. Actually, I guess it is semantic, but it's dual use. If you copied `\Cref` to `\Crefnew`, you'd take account of the reasoning on page 10. But, of course, lots of the time you may well not think it worth the additional faff.